# How do I change text color following some conditions in a table column in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have some conditions with if, else statement and the value of the variable "Remark" will change following the conditions.

```
if($income==($paid + $deduction)){
    $remark="Paid";
}
else if($paid > 0){
    $remark="Have Due";
}
else{
    $remark="Not Paid";
}
```

Now I want to echo the results in various color as like if paid it will be green or if not paid it will be red. I have to show the result in a table column.

```
<td align="center"><big><b><?php echo $remark?></b></big></td>
```

how can I do that? anybody, please help.

Comment: You could add a class style for each case. Let‘s say the user paid you will add a class called paid. In the stylesheet then you can style it.

Comment: how can i do that? i am very new. can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need something like this:

```
if($income==($paid + $deduction)){
    $class = "paid";
    $remark="Paid";
}
else if($paid > 0){
    $class = "due";
    $remark="Have Due";
}
else{
    $class = "notpaid";
    $remark="Not Paid";
}
```

And as HTML

```
<td align="center"><big><b class="<?php $class; ?>"><?php echo $remark; ?></b></big></td>
```

And as style:

```
.paid {
    color: green;
}

.due {
    color: orange;
}

.notpaid {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add another varieble for class and add it to a td. something like this:

php:

```
   if($income==($paid + $deduction)){
                              $remark="Paid";
                              $class="green";
                          }
                          else if($paid > 0){
                              $remark="Have Due";
                          }
                          else{
                              $remark="Not Paid";
                              $class="red";
                          }
```

html:

```
  <td align="center" class="<?php echo $class; ?>"><big><b><?php echo $remark?></b></big></td>
```

css:

```
  .red{
       color:red;
     }

  .green{
       color:green;
      }
```

hope i help :)